# Etymology of "bilbo"

Tags: etymology, origin-unknown

Here's what "*[bilbo](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bilbo)*" means -

> ## Bilbo
>
> noun (1)
>
> > : a long bar of iron with sliding shackles used to confine the feet of
> >     prisoners especially on shipboard.
>
> noun (2)
>
> > : [SWORD](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sword)

---

[*Merriam Webster*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bilbo) provides a vague history and etymology for "*bilbo*" -

> **History and Etymology for *bilbo***
>
> Noun (1)
>
> > perhaps from *Bilboa*, Spain
>
> Noun (2)
>
> > *Bilboa*, *Bilbao*, Spain

---

*[Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=bilbo)* only suggests the etymology for *[noun (2)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bilbo#h2)* -

> **bilbo (n.)**
>   kind of sword esteemed for temper and elasticity, 1590s,
>   from Bilbao (in English Bilboa), town in northern Spain where swords
>   were made. The town name is Roman Bellum Vadum "beautiful ford" (over
>   the Nervion River).

---

and [*Lexico*](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/bilboes) states that it comes from -

> mid 16th century: of unknown origin.

for its [first meaning](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bilbo#h1).

---

Therefore, I would like to know more about the history and etymology of the word "*bilbo*", and how its [first meaning](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bilbo#h1) came into use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The origin appears to be just from the a kind of swords made in Bilbao (Spain). The term appears in writing  in Shakespeare’s works.  As ankle shackles the usage is from early 18th century:

---

[Bilbo n.](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/7txcxrq#sn2)
also bilboa, bilboe

> > [SE bilbo, bilboa, a high-quality sword, imported from Bilboa in Spain; Williams (1994) includes bilbo among the sword synons. used for penis]
>
> 1. (UK Und.) a ruffian’s sword; thus bilbo’s the word, it’s time for swords, i.e. fighting.
>
>    - c.1597  [UK]    Shakespeare Merry Wives of Windsor I i: *I combat challenge of this latten bilbo. [Ibid.] III v: To be compassed, like a good bilbo, in the circumference of a peck, hilt to the point, head to heel.*
> 2. ***in pl., iron ankle shackles, also called ‘iron-garters’.***
>
>    - 1703    [UK]    Hell Upon Earth 8: High Spirited *Fellows [...] put into Bilboes, and Handcuffs.*

(GDoS)

[image]
(Wikipedia)